# How can upload file wilth httput without param key?

Tags: android, multipartentity, http-put

I used to make the thhpput call by passing parameters like this picture
[httpput with param](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k48PN.png)

now i want to to change with body binay methode like this picture
[httpput body binary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwqia.png)

i found the solution in ios :

```
[request setHTTPBody: dataToUpload];
```

I need the solution in Android . thanks a lot

Comment: yes, as usual ... set content type, get output stream from http connection, copy file to the stream, close streams and that's it (it is not a multipartentity)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will have to set the appropriate content type, e.g  `application/octet-stream` and the write your content to the connections output stream.

```
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
outputStream.close();
```

This will transfer the raw binary data, if you want to upload a file, check https://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/

Comment: hehe why? why `DataOutputStream`?  why do we need abstraction of `DataOutputStream` ?  `connection.getOutputStream()` is `OutputStream` ... you can wrap it with some buffered stream but why  `DataOutputStream`?